# Installing Whirlpool gem fails?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install `digest-whirlpool` with `gem`, but it's getting an error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing digest-whirlpool:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/digest-whirlpool-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/digest-whirlpool-1.0.2/ext/digest/whirlpool/gem_make.out
```

Why would this be?

EDIT: Debian Testing, ruby 1:1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install the `-dev` version of ruby.

Try:

`sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev`

But if I may suggest, RVM (https://rvm.io) makes so much easier to handle different versions of ruby.